# Setting Up a Highly Available Red Hat Enterprise Virtualization Manager (RHEV 3.5)

Tags: redhat, virtualization

What are shared directories/shared components need to be mounted in order to set up HA RHEVM-3.5?

For RHEV 3.1, I found follows:

```
/usr/share/jasperreports-server-pro
/usr/share/ovirt-engine-dwh
/usr/share/ovirt-engine-reports
/usr/share/ovirt-engine
/var/lib/exports
/var/lib/ovirt-engine
/var/lib/pgsql
```

Available directories in RHEVM 3.5 are follows:

```
/usr/share/ovirt-engine
/var/lib/exports
/var/lib/ovirt-engine
/var/lib/pgsql
```

Some of the shared components are missing in RHEVM-3.5. I want to know the exact details of shared directories/components to setup HA rhevm 3.5!

Answer (score 0):

The supported way to get RHEV-M/oVirt HA is to use Hosted Engine.
You can follow the [Hosted Engine How-To](http://www.ovirt.org/documentation/how-to/hosted-engine/) that explain you how to achieve High Availability by running RHEV-M / ovirt-engine within a VM which can live migrate between the host in the cluster and is automatically re-started on a different host in case of a failure on the host previously running it. Data integrity can be achieved by using GlusterFS with replica-3 as storage for the Hosted Engine VM.

The How-To also explain how to migrate an existing setup to the Hosted Engine configuration.

Comment: Can you add more details in your answer? e.g. what is the content of the link? How this can solve the problem? Also can you provide an example based on OP code?

Comment: @Athafoud thanks for the review, I've edited the answer.